# Sum notation upper indicator bigger that lower

Tags: summation, notation, arithmetic

Does $\sum^{0}_{i=1}i = 0 $ ? Can be upper indicator smaller than the $i=1$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be, but it depends on the case.
For example, if you were to take the natural numbers: $\sum^{n}_{k=1}i$, then the closed form for this sum is $\sum^{n}_{k=1}i= i*n$ and substituting $n=0$ gives you a desired example

Comment: for $n =1$ $\sum^{n-1}_{i=1} (\frac{1}{n} - ln\frac{i+1}{i}) = 0$ , is it wright ?

Comment: Yes, that's an example.

Comment: Your example doesn’t make sense to me. What is $k$ in $k* n$? Its the index in your sum...

Comment: @PrudiiArca I'm not sure by the question, but $k*n$ is a closed form for that particular sum. Meaning, that the sum on the left can be represented by the equation on the right. I.e, $\sum^{n}_{k=1} = k*n$

Comment: I think you want $k$ to be fixed and the sum be indexed by something else, say $i$. The closed form of $\sum \limits_{k=0}^k k$ is $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and not $kn$...

Comment: @PrudiiArca No, you're correct. I wrote it incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

For $a,b\in\Bbb Z$ I live by the definition $$\sum_{k=a}^b f(k)=\sum_{\{k\in \Bbb Z\,:\, a\le k\le b\}}f(k)$$

Therefore the sum is $0$ when $b<a$.

Comment: Assuming empty sum is 0

Comment: @MaximeWeill What would you assume it to be? $27$?

Comment: Lol. I think that's an important part to mention to answer the question.